# Why is this a faithfully flat extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> How can I see that the map of rings $f \colon A = \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}[a_2,a_4,a_6] \to B = \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}[a_2,a_4,r]$ given by $a_2 \mapsto a_2 + 3r$, $a_4 \mapsto a_4 + 2a_2 r+ 3r^2$ and $a_6 \mapsto a_4 r + a_2r^2 + r^3$ is faithfully flat ?

This appears in Bauer's [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311328) on computing the homotopy of *tmf*. Here are some simplifications that I can make :

Let's rename everything and have it as a morphism $f \colon A = R[x,y,z] \to B =R[x,y,z]$. We can write it as a composite of 3 maps, the first one sending $ x \mapsto x + 3z$ and fixing $y,z$, the second one sending $y \mapsto y + 2xz + 3z^2$ and fixing $x,y$, and the last one sending $z \mapsto z^3 + xz^2 + yz$ and fixing $x,y$. The first two are isomorphisms so they are faithfully flat, I guess that the 3rd one is too, which would finish the proof.

Maybe this more general statement holds:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring (integral domain ?) and let $p(x) \in R[x]$ be a monic polynomial. Then the map of $R$-algebras $R[x] \to R[x]$ sending $x \mapsto p(x)$ is a faithfully flat extension of rings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your last question reduces to whether $R[p(x)]\subset R[x]$ is faithfully flat. But since $p$ is monic $R[x]$ is free over $R[p(x)]$, and you are done.

Comment: I see it now yeah. Thanks